# What is the difference when using forks=0 and forks==0?

Tags: c, fork

What is the difference between `if(fork()=0)` and `if(fork()==0)`?
When it returns 0, it is the child, but what if it its ==0?

Comment: It scares me that you're playing with `fork()` without knowing the difference between `=` and `==` (it's probably just my inner SysAdmin screaming)

Comment: Have you tried this? The first one should not even compile since the target of the assignment is not an lvalue...

Comment: That's how BASIC programmers try to write C code.

Comment: the first one works, thats why i was wondering why

Comment: You're probably doing some mistakes compiling, the first one cannot compile, not just because the code is ill-formed, but also because it has no sense at all, that's the same as `0 = 1` (well, assuming your `fork` is returning `int`...). Are you sure the code you provided is the same code you tested? What compiler and version are you using?

Answer (score 8):

`=` is the assignment operator and `==` is the equality comparison operator.  You ought to get a compilation warning or error when you use `fork() = 0`.

Comment: +1 about compilation warning/error.

Comment: `fun() {
  printf("A");
  fork();
  printf("B");
  if (fork() != 0) {
     printf("C");
     fork();
     printf("D");
  }
  printf("E");
}`

Comment: @jay: That example doesn't match either of the two in your question. `!=` is not `=` or `==`. http://ideone.com/ZploBs

Comment: @jaylopp: What does that code have to do with your question or this answer? There's no use of either `=` or `==`, only `!=`.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the `if` is never entered. In the second, the `if` is entered if after the result of `fork` the currently executing code is in the "child" process.

Comment: To compound on this, = is the assignment operator and == is the equality operator.  An assignment is going to return true whether or not fork() does... but checking the equality of the fork() return value (using ==) would properly check.

Comment: @TobyLawrence well, no. "An assignment is going to return true" - except if you assign 0 to the LHS.

Comment: @Toby: An assignment returns whatever was on the right hand side of itself. In this case, that is `0`, which is implicitly convertible to `false`, not `true`.

Comment: Sorry, you're both right.  I meant to say it's going to return false because of the assignment to 0. :)

Comment: @BillyONeal: An assignment does not quite return what was on the right-hand side. E.g., if `x` is an `int`, `x = 3.5` returns 3, not 3.5. An assignment returns what it assigned, which is the right-hand side converted to the type of the left-hand side.

Answer (score 2):

```
fork() = 0
```

is assignment

```
fork() == 0
```

tests for equality

Comment: equality, not equivalence :)

Comment: I would say equality rather than equivalence. Equivalence usually means `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` in STL land; so this might confuse people. Though I acknowledge the question is tagged with C, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

`=` assigns a value to a variable, `==` checks for equality.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case if(fork()=0) is an assignment and it is always true. This condition never false.
Whereas if(fork()==0) checks the condition whether fork() has a value equal to 0 or not.

Comment: No, an assignment is not always true, it returns the assigned value; actually, `x = 0` always evaluates to `false`.